# How would I write this program in Python 3.3.2?

Tags: python

This is Guess_The_Number program I wrote in Python:

```
import random
print("Hello! Today we are going to play Guess The Number!")
number = int(input("Guess a number between 0 and 5"))
random_number = random.randint(0, 5)
if number == random_number:
    print("You won!")
    print("Your prize is...")
    print("Nothing!")
else:
    print("You lost!")
    print("The number was %s") % (random_number)
```

I tested it and it returned:

```
print("The number was {0}").format(random_number)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Then I tried:

```
print("The number was {0}").format(random_number)
```

for the last print statement

It stated:

```
print("The number was {0}").format(random_number) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misplaced parenthesis

```
print("The number was {0}".format(random_number))
```

**SMALL NOTE** -  It works in Py2

EDit - I meant your program works in Py2 that is `("The number was {0}").format(random_number)` works in Py2

Comment: Additionally, `print("The number was %s" % random_number)`, works just fine in both 2.x and 3.x - although it is better to use `.format`

Comment: @Scironic I guess you didn't get my usage of English ... :) ... Sorry

Comment: @bhargavRao I did don't worry! I'm just showing that `%` based formatting, which OP initially used, also works fine.

Comment: @Scironic Oh .. I didn't read your comment properly then. My bad :( ...